# what would happen when i try to continue the loop within the catch block

Tags: c#, .net

what would happen while searching the file through a string and could i try to **continue** the loop within the catch block against locked windows file in order to read next file.

```
TextReader rff = null;
try
{
    rff = new StreamReader(fi.FullName);
    String lne1 = rff.ReadToEnd();
    if (lne1.IndexOf(txt) >= 0)
    {
        z = fi.FullName;
        list22.Add(fi.FullName);
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code ?

Comment: So when you search through files, and get an exception because you hit a locked file, you'd like to continue the loop in the catch block?

Comment: "full relevant sample code", perhaps. The code currently posted does not really show situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you'll have a try-catch around the statement where you are accessing the file within the loop. Then you can continue the loop after catching any exception.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the exception is caught by a try-catch nested inside the loop, you should be able to `continue` the loop no problem.

Answer (score 0):

While catching the exception try to catch only the most specific exception that may be thrown, so if you are looking to handle a locking situation you would look to catch the System.IO.IOException which is raised when files are used by other proccesses.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do some cleanup to do you should add a finally:

```
foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{

    var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
    StreamReader reader;
    try
    {
        reader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName);
        SomeMethodThatThrowsIOException();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        continue;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
}
```

or even better (since StreamReader implements IDisposable)

```
foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{

    try
    {

        var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
        {
            SomeMethodThatThrowsIOException();
        } 
    }
    catch (IOException ex) { }

}
```